# Why do bracket[] and .loc work differently when creating multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm confused why bracket [] and .loc behave differently when creating multiple columns. I've looked into other similar questions but I couldn't get the answer.

For example,

```
>>> dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> df
                    A         B         C         D
2000-01-01 -1.011264 -1.751948  0.059012  0.514253
2000-01-02  0.596959  0.348866 -1.011628  0.950259
2000-01-03  0.305281  0.486400 -1.034534 -1.523402
2000-01-04 -0.880457  0.379837  2.023866  1.588379
2000-01-05 -1.142070 -0.168992 -0.391355  0.809820
2000-01-06 -0.335015  0.721563 -0.665120 -1.097811
2000-01-07 -0.160611 -0.601393 -0.257349 -0.830527
2000-01-08  0.197624 -0.082786  1.335873 -0.841006
```

If I create multiple columns with brackets, it works as below.

```
>>> df[['E','F']] = df[['A','B']]
>>> df
                   A         B         C         D         E         F
2000-01-01 -1.011264 -1.751948  0.059012  0.514253 -1.011264 -1.751948
2000-01-02  0.596959  0.348866 -1.011628  0.950259  0.596959  0.348866
2000-01-03  0.305281  0.486400 -1.034534 -1.523402  0.305281  0.486400
2000-01-04 -0.880457  0.379837  2.023866  1.588379 -0.880457  0.379837
2000-01-05 -1.142070 -0.168992 -0.391355  0.809820 -1.142070 -0.168992
2000-01-06 -0.335015  0.721563 -0.665120 -1.097811 -0.335015  0.721563
2000-01-07 -0.160611 -0.601393 -0.257349 -0.830527 -0.160611 -0.601393
2000-01-08  0.197624 -0.082786  1.335873 -0.841006  0.197624 -0.082786
```

However, if I use .loc method for creating multiple columns, it doesn't work.

```
>>> df.loc[:,['H','I']] = df[['A','B']]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 189, in __setitem__
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 167, in _get_setitem_indexer
    return self._convert_tuple(key, is_setter=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 248, in _convert_tuple
    idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i, is_setter=is_setter)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1246, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: "None of [Index(['H', 'I'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

.loc method works well when creating only one column. (square bracket works as well.)

```
>>> df.loc[:,'G'] = df['A']
>>> df
                   A         B         C         D         E         F         G
2000-01-01 -1.011264 -1.751948  0.059012  0.514253 -1.011264 -1.751948 -1.011264
2000-01-02  0.596959  0.348866 -1.011628  0.950259  0.596959  0.348866  0.596959
2000-01-03  0.305281  0.486400 -1.034534 -1.523402  0.305281  0.486400  0.305281
2000-01-04 -0.880457  0.379837  2.023866  1.588379 -0.880457  0.379837 -0.880457
2000-01-05 -1.142070 -0.168992 -0.391355  0.809820 -1.142070 -0.168992 -1.142070
2000-01-06 -0.335015  0.721563 -0.665120 -1.097811 -0.335015  0.721563 -0.335015
2000-01-07 -0.160611 -0.601393 -0.257349 -0.830527 -0.160611 -0.601393 -0.160611
2000-01-08  0.197624 -0.082786  1.335873 -0.841006  0.197624 -0.082786  0.197624
```

I'm confused about why .loc is not functioning as square brackets in creating multiple columns. I prefer explicit way as .loc[] does, and I'm quite bothered by the fact that its functionality is sometimes limited. Am I missing something? Could I ask why they work differently in this case?

*** Addition to the original question ***

.loc[] method generates NaN columns when it is assigned to existing columns. For example,

`>>>df[['E','F']] = df[['A','B']]`
`>>> df
                   A         B    ...            E         F
2000-01-01  0.934380 -0.321112    ...     0.934380 -0.321112
2000-01-02 -0.760045  0.646212    ...    -0.760045  0.646212
2000-01-03  0.645231 -0.910008    ...     0.645231 -0.910008
2000-01-04 -1.117132  2.595804    ...    -1.117132  2.595804
2000-01-05 -1.273579  0.291202    ...    -1.273579  0.291202
2000-01-06  0.142610 -0.368157    ...     0.142610 -0.368157
2000-01-07  0.567490 -1.598343    ...     0.567490 -1.598343
2000-01-08  1.300694  0.498405    ...     1.300694  0.498405`

I generated new columns E,F and tried to assign new values from C,D using .loc[] method.

`>>>df.loc[:,['E','F']] = df[['C','D']]`

`>>>df
                   A         B         C         D   E   F
2000-01-01  0.934380 -0.321112  0.747195 -0.991180 NaN NaN
2000-01-02 -0.760045  0.646212 -0.121421  2.262384 NaN NaN
2000-01-03  0.645231 -0.910008  0.170989 -1.552823 NaN NaN
2000-01-04 -1.117132  2.595804  0.569809  1.575253 NaN NaN
2000-01-05 -1.273579  0.291202  0.688443 -0.581674 NaN NaN
2000-01-06  0.142610 -0.368157 -0.674774 -1.961087 NaN NaN
2000-01-07  0.567490 -1.598343 -1.346179 -1.139205 NaN NaN
2000-01-08  1.300694  0.498405 -0.358015 -1.637471 NaN NaN`

It seems that using .loc[] still makes problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously said it is done intentionally. Here are a few examples:

It looks it has to do with `__getitem__`, which is called when using `[]`

Let's look at a few errors:

`df['H']` returns a simular error to `df.loc[:,'H']` Both seem to use `pandas\core\frame.py __getitem__` which is why they behave the same when setting:

```
df['H'] = df['A']
df.loc[:, 'H'] = df['A']
```

When you use `loc` with a list (`df.loc[:, ['H', 'I']]` or `df.loc[:, ['H']]`) it is no longer using `pandas\core\frame.py __getitem__` It uses `pandas\core\indexing.py __getitem__` which sets `raise_missing` to False in `_validate_read_indexer`

There is a [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1243-L1253) in this function that provides some information:

```
    # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in
    # some cases (e.g. setting) in which "raise_missing" will be False
```

`df[['H','I']]` uses `pandas\core\frame.py __getitem__` which is why you there is no error when setting.

This is just my guess as to what is going on.

Your other question about `df.loc[:,['E','F']] = df[['C','D']]` is explained in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics) under "The correct way to swap column values is by using raw values". You should use `to_numpy()`: `df.loc[:,['E','F']] = df[['C','D']].to_numpy()`

Comment: Thanks, it scratches my itches. I was wondering if it was a bug. For me df.log[:'H'] = df['A'] didn't make any problem though.

Comment: @MatthewSon Correct it should not raise and error because it is treated the same as `df['H'] = df['A']`

Comment: @Chris Awesome explanation!  +1

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior put in to pandas after 0.21.0  See [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated).

The root of your error message is this part, where either 'H' or 'I' is missing in the dataframe:

```
df.loc[:,['H','I']]
```

Using a list with .loc and missing values will raise a KeyError.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried including new column names but found another problem- and modified my question. What triggers this problem in your opinion?

Comment: Also, it's still strange that .loc works when it comes to creating a single column...

Comment: Yes... the docs specifically mention list with missing value is deprecated to generate a KeyError.  Not really sure why.