# Preferred method for selecting pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose you have a DataFrame like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C": [7,8,9]})
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  4  7
# 1  2  5  8
# 2  3  6  9
```

We have many ways to select a single cell, such as:

```py
df["B"][1]
df["B"].loc[1]
df.loc[1,"B"]
df.loc[1]["B"]
```

I may not remember all of them, but my question is whether all these ways are equivalent, or which one is better and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte)

Comment: [Why do bracket and .loc work differently when creating multiple columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810385/) - [Python: Pandas Series - Why use loc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/)

Comment: + https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html.

Comment: Neither of these would be preferred for selection of a single value, instead, use [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) or `.iat`